# What does apply method in pandas dataframe pass to the function applied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a novice in pandas and curious about what exactly pandas pass to the function specified in the apply method parameter. 
Here is an example from [introduction of data science in python course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/lecture/yO8DX/group-by)

With the data below:

```
                       Category  Quantity  Weight (oz.)
Item                                                   
Pack                       Pack         1          33.0
Tent                    Shelter         1          80.0
Sleeping Pad              Sleep         1          27.0
Sleeping Bag              Sleep         1          20.0
Toothbrush/Toothpaste    Health         1           2.0
Sunscreen                Health         1           5.0
Medical Kit              Health         1           3.7
Spoon                   Kitchen         1           0.7
Stove                   Kitchen         1          20.0
Water Filter            Kitchen         1           1.8
Water Bottles           Kitchen         2          35.0
Pack Liner              Utility         1           1.0
Stuff Sack              Utility         1           1.0
Trekking Poles          Utility         1          16.0
Rain Poncho            Clothing         1           6.0
Shoes                  Clothing         1          12.0
Hat                    Clothing         1           2.5
```

The goal is to calculate the total weight (Weight x Quantity) by category. I already understand we need to use Groupby method to split the data in chunks then use apply to do the rest.

Here is the **correct answer** to the question:

```
print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b]), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity'))
```

**That's where I got confused. I don't know why it would work. What exactly does Pandas pass to the anonymous function? Is it always firstly the Dataframe itself then the names of the columns(if specified)?**

I'll be much appreciated if you could help me understand this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need multiple columns first and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df['Weight (oz.)'].mul(df['Quantity']).groupby(df['Category']).sum().reset_index(name='wsum')
```

Or:

```
(df.assign(wsum = df['Weight (oz.)'].mul(df['Quantity']))
   .groupby('Category', as_index=False)['wsum'].sum())
```

Your solution should be changed with multiple per groups, but if large DataFrame or many groups it is slow:

```
df1 = (df.groupby('Category')     
        .apply(lambda x: (x['Weight (oz.)'] * x['Quantity']).sum()).reset_index(name='wsum'))
```

---

> I don't know why it would work. What exactly does Pandas pass to the anonymous function? Is it always firstly the Dataframe itself then the names of the columns(if specified)?

I think reason should be pandas mapping lambda variables, so `df` is mapped to each group, `a` is mapped to string `Weight (oz.)` and `b` to string `Quantity`:

```
print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: print (df), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity'))
print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: print (a), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity'))
print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: print (b), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity'))
```

But this is really not standard way in pandas how pass columns names in functions.

Comment: Thanks! But I have the correct answer above, my question is that  what does apply method pass to the function we specify (in this case the lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b])). It will always pass the dataframe and the column names we set?

Comment: @朱原昊 - Give me a sec

Comment: Appreciated! But $print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b]), 'Weight (oz.)', 'Quantity'))
$ is the correct answer, I just don't know why it would work

Answer (score 1):

```
print(df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda df,a,b: sum(df[a] * df[b])
```

in the above code, as you already said first one is dataframe, but python only knows that a, b are just identifiers. But when you pass a and b as subscript, df[a] - python implicitly convert to the index

Comment: So it depends on how the function is defined?

Comment: Yes Exactly.. If you know working of lambda functions, it won't be difficult to grasp